# User Validation Through $_SESSION On PHP

Tags: php, validation, session

I'm trying to validate a user using the $_SESSION superglobal on PHP but it seems $_Session does not like me any help is kindly apprecciated, i have the following code called index.php:

```
 '<?php
 'session_start();
 'require("administratorcheck.php");
  //i have tried require_once "administratorcheck.php"
  '?>
```

where in this case administratorcheck.php looks like this for the validation:

```
        <?php
      $errorMessage =  'Your Login Information Is Not Correct';
     if(isset($_POST['username'])){
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];

    $adminUser = "admin";
    $adminPass = "donkeyKong";

if(($username!=$adminUser)||($password !=$adminPass))
{
   echo  $errorMessage;
}else{
// session_register('admin');
$_SESSION['admin'] = $username;
header("index.php");
exit();
}

}
 if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])!= 'admin')
 {
 echo '<h2>You Are Not Authorized To View This File</h2><br/>
 <table width = "400" border = "2">
 <form action = "administratorcheck.php" method="post" >
 <tr>
<td colspan = "2">You May Be Able To Login Here</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td width="108">Admin Username:</td>
<td width="250"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:98%"/>                                                            
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:98%"/></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" 

value="Log Me In"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</br>
</br>
<a href = "../">Click Here To Return To The Index Page</a>';
exit();
 }
```

?>

Comment: `$_SESSION does not like you` doesn't sound like a valid PHP error code. What exactly happened? What isn't working? Did you get an error?

Comment: Why are your index.php code lines starting with `'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

the line below is not doing what you think it is doing.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])!= 'admin')
```

If you break it down into smaller parts you will see. Looking at the first part you see that you get a boolean back from `isset`

```
$isAdminFieldSet = isset($_SESSION['admin']) // this returns a boolean
```

Now in your if statement you are actually doing

```
if($isAdminFieldSet != 'admin') {
```

which is really

```
if(true != 'admin') {
```

or

```
if (false != 'admin') {
```

## Solution

yes an admin check

```
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == 'admin')  {
   // user is an admin
   ...
}
```

not an admin check

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['admin']) || $_SESSION['admin'] != 'admin' )  {
   // user is not an admin
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think in admin check, `$_SESSION['admin'] == 'admin'` is enough. Correct me if I'm wrong. Oh, and same thing with the 'not-an-admin check' as well.

Comment: yea you're right. I was just being extra verbose as an example so user2097683 could see what was going on.

Comment: Great. +1 for clarifying to him.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Noah for taking the time to explain it to I do appreciate your kind help and Mr. Mido thanks a lot for your short code too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])!= 'admin')
```

isset returns a boolean and thus will never be equal to 'admin'